# Using SSIS to import data from Facebook API

Tags: sql-server, facebook-graph-api, ssis, facebook-fql

I would like to ask you if there is anyone who has any experience in how to import data from facebook api into sql server. I have searched around a lot but not sure where I should start. My goals is to import basically all data about one public page and then buil reports in ssrs showing trends of the traffic and activity on the page.

I am completely new in development/data analytics in social media. So, I would appreciate any tips where to start. Also, what shall I use FQL or Facebook Graph api.

Thanks for any tips :)

Comment: Look into using the Graph API.  You will need a good deal of code to access the API and then more code to write to a database.